# CSS dropdown menu - 3rd level issue

Tags: html, css

Ive got a 3 leve dropdown menu and the 3rd level sub-menu displays next to the 2nd level menu item like it should, except for a gap.
The 2nd level is set to a width of 100px so I've absolutely positioned the 3rd level to top:0, left:100px so it displays to the right of the 2nd level, but there's a gap. If I change left:100px to left:97px there is no gap. Why is this?

The HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Initialise for 3 tiers */
nav ul, ul li ul, ul li ul li ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li, ul li ul li, ul li ul li ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left; 
}

/* Link Appearance for 3 tiers */
nav ul li a, ul li ul li a, ul li ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#666;
    padding:5px 10px;
    float:left; 
}

nav ul li a:hover, ul li ul li a:hover, ul li ul li ul li a:hover {
    background:#C00;
}

/* 2nd Tier */
nav ul li {
    position:relative;  
}

nav ul li > ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:0;
    width:100px;    
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;  
}

/* 3rd Tier */ 
nav ul li ul li {
    position:relative;  
}

nav ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;  
}

nav ul li ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqEfW/2/)

Comment: are you using chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the gap between the menus. They need to be adjacent or even overlap for this hover trick to work.

So instead of specifying

```
left: 100px;
```

do something like

```
left: 100%; 
/* or even */
left: 99%;
```

This will cause the 3rd layer to be adjacent to the second layer menu, or even overlap the second slightly (for 99%), allowing you to move the mouse without any interruptions that close the menu. And you won't have to worry about the width of the menus either.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqEfW/5/

If you want to keep the gap for the look of it, you can give the 3rd layer ul a padding:

```
nav ul li ul li ul {
    ....
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Ad demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/tqEfW/9/

That said, from a UX point of view, menus with 3 layers are very hard to use and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the great info! I agree 3 layer menus should be avoided - just needed to know how in case :)

Answer (score 2):

using percentage instead of pixel for this issue:
try `left:100%` and check result

```
nav ul li ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgtv/tqEfW/6/)

also you don't need to write `ul li ul li ul li a` or like so.simply you can write:

```
ul ul ul a{
your CSS code
}
```

Comment: As simple as that eh? :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah! that's it ;) @JasonCollier

Answer (score 0):

If you create CSS selectors like `ul.first-level > li` or `ul.second-level > li`  it will only select the li that are inmediately after the `ul` with class `first-level` (or with class `second-level`, respectively).

In this way, without interating a lot of `ul li ul li ul` that can be really hard to *read* you can control the appearance of any complex nested list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I must admit it was doing my head in counting the ul's and li's :)

Comment: Good suggestion, although this should generally be in a comment, since it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

***Its looks like you know how to solve it but your question is why this is happening.***

Now in your code you put the width 100px to ***ul***. but the ***li*** didn't have nay width. now both width is not same thing. width in ***ul*** is the width of this list area. And width in ***li*** means width of each individual list item. In your case your

```
  ul li a
  {
   padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

now the padding of ***a*** do not full the full area. and you put the background color at ***ul li a*** so the much area its covering(not sure 'cover' is the appropriate word to mention it) its showing dark in back and around 3px left so its showing white.

If you put

```
  ul li a
  {
   padding: 5px 10.1px;
  }
```

You will see the ***li*** have no gap[#123] between levels of menu.

Instead of setting the background to ***ul li a*** if you set it to ***ul*** you can see there is no gap[#123]

***#123***  The actual white area is not  gap. The ***ul*** is 100px but text including the padding of 10px in left and right not filling the total 100px. Its filling only 97px so when you are putting the width as 97px its showing no white area. But when it is 100px this showing the background on 97px as black and the rest 3px white which looks like a gap.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So using padding to control the size of the menu item is probably not the best way if I want things to be pixel perfect. Is it better to set a width for the `<li>` as opposed to using padding?

Comment: You are welcome. If i am not wrong you knew that if you put the width 97px then there is no gap, means you have a solution. At the end of your question you asked "Why is this?" so instead of giving you a solution for your problem i describe the problem. So if i am not wrong this should be selected as answer so in future people can get understand why this kind of problem arise. In stackoverflow we ask and answer question not just solving our problem, also make a reference for future.

Comment: The question was not "please solve my code" The answer which is accepted do not describe the issue "WHY THE PROBLEM IS HAPPENING"